# LOG is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd

```
FILE=Z:\AWS_NLT1S_DUMP\AM_CO\ACWF_DUMP_01.DMP,Z:\AWS_NLT1S_DUMP\AM_CO\ACWF_DUMP_02.DMP 
LOG=Z:\AWS_NLT1S_DUMP\AM_CO\ACWF_DUMP.LOG TABLES=%AM SCHEMAS=ACWF FILESIZE=10GB
```

I am trying to export an Oracle dump and generate log files for the export. However, the log files cannot be generated because of the error stated in the title.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: To assign a variable in a batch file you have to use set: `set file=...` or  `set log=...`

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it @Samuel. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In batch, you assign variables using the `set` command; you should use:

```bat
set "FILE=Z:\AWS_NLT1S_DUMP\AM_CO\ACWF_DUMP_01.DMP,Z:\AWS_NLT1S_DUMP\AM_CO\ACWF_DUMP_02.DMP"
set "LOG=Z:\AWS_NLT1S_DUMP\AM_CO\ACWF_DUMP.LOG TABLES=%AM SCHEMAS=ACWF FILESIZE=10GB"
```

See `set /?` for more information.